# Comparing SQL Data and Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I currently have 2 scripts that I run through Powershell, one of them pulls employee data out of an SQL Database (main thing I am looking at is who is the manager to each employee), and the other script pulls employee information out of AD. As of right now I have to set the 2 output files side by side and compare them because the SQL Database is constantly being upkept, while AD isn't, and in return AD has employees that say their manager is someone who is no longer their manager.

What I am wondering is, is there a way to completely automate this process so that I can run a single script that would compare the two files and possible highlight each line that has a difference, making it so that I don't manually have to check which employees have differences.

If that is not possible, or just very difficult, I would even be happy to keep and run the original 2 scripts, then having a third script to just do the comparing and highlighting. Let me know if you need anything other information, or if I need to clarify a few things.

Comment: Check cmdlet [Compare-Object](http://ss64.com/ps/compare-object.html) and you can automate this process. Pull data from source 1 => transform to unified format, pull data from source2 => transform => compare => take action.

Comment: So after looking at Compare-Object, I have a question. Will this still work even if the files aren't identical in column names? For example, AD has a field EmployeeID and SQL has the field EMP_ID. The employee ID's are the same, just the naming format isn't consistent between AD and SQL.

Comment: Unify both sources, use Select-Object and rename them in the same manner. It will be more readable and easier to maintain in the future.